# Jersey 2.22 in Dropwizard 0.9.3 set BeanParam variables as null

Tags: jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I'm trying to write endpoint for registration. All user data is described in POJO which I set in endpoint params with @BeanParam. If endpoint annotated to consume multipart form, all POJO params from request are null.

But if I annotate endpoint to consume regular form and replace @FormDataParam with @FormParam all data are set

POJO:

```
public class RegisterUserParams {

@NotEmpty
@Email
@FormDataParam("email")
private String email;

@NotEmpty
@FormDataParam("name")
private String name;

@NotEmpty
@FormDataParam("phone")
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]+$", message = "phone must contain only digits")
private String phone;

@NotEmpty
@FormDataParam("password")
@Size(min = 6, max = 50)
private String password;

// more fields, default constructor, getters and setters
```

Endpoint

```
@POST
@UnitOfWork
@Path("/register")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void registerUser(@Valid @BeanParam RegisterUserParams form) {
     // endpoint code
}
```

Dropwizard version 0.9.3, Jersey version 2.22